# After session timeout what happens if we post the data to database through the ajax call in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have one submit form. suppose if session is timeout if we click on the submit button what happens and that to it is an ajax call for submitting the data.

Answer (score 0):

The Session object will be null. There is always a possibility that the Session object will be null, not only from a timeout, but a server reboot, application pool recycle, application update will restart your website and clear all Session objects.

Comment: bro but it is showing an error in my website.how to resolve this